# SwiftUI: ZStack with scaleEffect - how to align scaled image to bottom?

Tags: swiftui, scale, vertical-alignment, image-scaling, zstack

I have a ZStack in which an Image is presented.
The image needs to be scaled in some cases.

I am failing on aligning the scaled image on the bottom of the ZStack, it is always presented in the middle.

I tried ZStack(alignment: .bottom) in combination with .alignmentGuide(.bottom) for the image, but this does not change the outcome.

Also putting a VStack around the image and placing a Spacer() above it does not change the result.

The HStack is not relevant and is only shown, because I need an ZStack in this construct. But The main issue is with the VStack, that it does not move after scaling in the  Space of the ZStack.

It seems like .scaleEffect just uses position and frame of the original image and places the scaled image in the middle. Is this a limitation of scaleEffect? What other function can be used?

This is my View (reduced code): // I colored the background purple, to show the full size of the ZStack

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Color.purple
        Image(battlingIndividual.getMonster().getStatusImageName(battlingIndividual.status))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .scaleEffect(battlingIndividual.getMonster().size.scaleValue)
        HStack() {
            SkillViews(battlingIndividual: battlingIndividual)
            Spacer()
        }
      }
}
```

The outcome is this:

[image: current outcome]

But it should look like this:
[image: desired outcome]

EDIT: I added a Background to the image, in order to show that the image is centered in the ZStack.
[image: Image-Background in gray]

---

**Solution:**
We don´t need an alignment in this case, we need an anchor:

```
.scaleEffect(battlingIndividual.getMonster().size.scaleValue, anchor: .bottom)
```

Solution Image:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.
.scaleEffect uses its own anchor, which can be set to .bottom.

[scaleEffect(_:anchor:) Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/scaleeffect(_:anchor:)-4l17j)

Therefore I needed only to add "ancor: .bottom" to the scaleEffect.

```
.scaleEffect(battlingIndividual.getMonster().size.scaleValue, anchor:
.bottom)
```

for the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, put your Image in a VStack and a Spacer() above the image and your Images will be on the bottom of the Stack. The alignment .bottom is only to aline multiple views with each other, but you are not having multiple views in your Stack. The HStack doesn't count for the alignment.

If I try this out in my example and scale the image down,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "ladybug")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment:                 
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "hare")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    Image(systemName: "hare")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    Image(systemName: "hare")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this.

[image]

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: I tried the spacer too, but it didnt work.    VStack() { Spacer(), Image() }   - same result

Comment: Can you tell me what the SkillViews is doing?

Comment: The skill view presents another set of up to 10 images at the left side of the ZStack. Here the alignment works properly and the Spacer() works. The images are centered here as well, of course, if one image is presented it is in the middle, if two images are presented, one is above and one is below the middle.

Comment: you do not scale the image. if you scale the image the bug will be smaller but always show up in the middle instead of moving down...

Comment: I scaled the image down and it is still at the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this view container `ZStack` is a one cell view, so you need to align not ZStack which tights to content, but entire `HStack` containing those monster cells, like

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {    // << here !!
   ForEach ... {
      MonsterCellView()
   }
}
```

Comment: you are right, I am using a LazyHStack, but also the "alignment: .bottom" there does not help. It should be in the ZStack.Because when I put text above the Image, a Spacer inbetween, the Image still does not move to the bottom but keeps its space...